# Faster way to execute loops

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and need help in figuring out a faster way to execute my code. Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub loop()
For i = 1 To 100000
check_cell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i)
  For j = 1 To 14430
    text_to_check = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & j)
    text_to_fill = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & j)
    If InStr(check_cell, text_to_check) Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & i).Value = text_to_fill
    End If
  Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I know that I am using a very brutal way by running the system through a loop 1,443,000,000 times. Any help on shortening this would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Based on suggestion, I tried with new code using variants but nothing seems to be happening. Would you be able to tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

```
Sub loop_2()
    Dim varray_1 As Variant
    Dim varray_2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    varray_1 = Sheets("L1").Range("I2:I39997").Value
    varray_2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G1:G14394").Value
    For i = UBound(varray_1, 1) To LBound(varray_1, 1) Step -1
        For j = UBound(varray_2, 1) To LBound(varray_2, 1) Step -1
            If varray_1(i, 1) = varray_2(j, 1) Then
                Sheets("L1").Range("L" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & j).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Transfer your data to arrays first, process on the arrays, write arrays back to sheet at end.  (b) Unless there is a possibility that a cell can be changed to one of the `text_to_fill` values on Sheet2, and then that value can then be changed to a later `text_to_fill` value, you can put an `Exit For` after you change the cell.  (And, if you do have values where one `text_to_fill` needs to change to another, simplify the data on Sheet2 so that you can't.)

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't understand your solution. I don't know how to process arrrays. Would it be possible for you to share a sample code?

Comment: The code in your edit works for me, but obviously it is doing a full match instead of a partial match.  It would still be faster to write the results to an array while processing, and then write the array to the sheet in one operation at the end.  (I am assuming that none of your cells in `L1!I:I` contain formulae which are dependent on `L1!L:L`.)  It's the writing of information to the sheet that will be consuming the bulk of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but it should at least give an idea of how to put the values into arrays, process everything "in-memory", and then write the results out.

```
Sub loop()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim check_cell() As Variant
    Dim result() As Variant
    Dim text_to_check() As Variant
    Dim text_to_fill() As Variant

    check_cell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1:I100000").Value
    result = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:J100000").Value
    text_to_check = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D14430").Value
    text_to_fill = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1:E14430").Value
    For i = 1 To 100000
        For j = 1 To 14430
            If InStr(check_cell(i, 1), text_to_check(j, 1)) Then
                 result(i, 1) = text_to_fill(j, 1)
                 If i = 1 Then
                     Debug.Print "check_cell=" & check_cell(i, 1)
                     Debug.Print "j=" & j
                     Debug.Print "text_to_check=" & text_to_check(j, 1)
                     Debug.Print "text_to_fill=" & text_to_fill(j, 1)
                 End If
                 ' exit as soon as first match is made
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:J100000").Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested using your code. Definitely runs way faster but there is no output in column J. It was blank to begin with and after running the code it stays the same.

Comment: Do you have any of your `text_to_check` (i.e. Sheet2!D1:D14430) cells that are empty?  Your code is designed to store only the last match into column J and, if (for instance) cell D14430 is empty then it will be the last match.

Comment: @AkshayNayar - P.S. Do you want to store the last match?  Or the first match?

Comment: Thanks. I want to store the first match only. Also none of the cells in range D1:D14430 is empty. Column J is empty though.

Comment: Noticed an interesting thing. When I deliberately fill column J with some data it gets deleted after the code is run. I am guessing that the code is writing blanks on the given range but I am not able to figure out why. There are no blanks in the other ranges that I am passing into array on Sheet2

Comment: @AkshayNayar - I have edited the answer to exit the inner loop as soon as a match is made.  I have also added in some `Debug.Print` statements which will write values to the Immediate Window (in the VBA editor, press Ctrl-G to display the Immediate Window it it isn't already displayed) while it is processing the first row.  Those values might give me a clue as to why it isn't working.  (If the code actually **does** work now that the `Exit For` is there, I might get you to run it again with the `Exit For` commented out to see what **was** wrong.)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The most cost here is using `InStr()`, but you should also:

- Declare your variables, `Variant` are slower
- Wrap your loops with

  ```
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
     ...
  End With
  ```
- Change cell addressing to `.Cell(10, i)` instead of `.Range("D" & j)`

My tests show it runs 50% faster, note that I had all cells empty, so the `InStr()` cost is relatively low in that case.